# Can i use Google's direction API only for distance and durition?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mapkit

In my iPhone app I'm using MapKit to show the user where he is, i also want to show him the total time and duration
to his destination.
Can i use Google direction API to do that?
What I'm planning to do is to ask for direction every few seconds (up to 2500 requests i know..)
and only show the "direction" and "duration" values from the response to the user.

Comment: can you explain.. "What I'm planning to do is to ask for direction every few seconds (up to 2500 requests i know..) "

Comment: I know there are some limitation when using the Google API, i accidentally wrote "direction" in my question, but what i wanted to ask is if i can show only DISTANCE & duration (without showing the direction instruction) and i also don't know if it is OK to draw the path over a MKMapView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

The JSON response includes distance and duration, e.g.

```
"duration": {
    "value": 74384,
    "text": "20 hours 40 mins"
},
"distance": {
    "value": 2137146,
    "text": "1,328 mi"
},
```

I would suggest only calling the API every minute or so.  You can use linear interpolation to work out the in-between values (your will have to estimate the speed to decrease distance by the right amount).

To implement this....

1. Frist save the time when the result is returned.

   `self.responseTime = [NSDate date];`
2. Calculate the speed that google used.

   `Speed = Distance / Time`

   So in the example the raw units are meters and seconds so

   `Speed = 2137146 / 74384 = 28.7... ms^1`
3. Use NSTimer to get a recurring callback every so often.  In the callback you need:

   1. Decrease time by the elapsed time since the response time.
   2. Decease the distance by the calculated speed * elapsed time since the response time.
   3. Update the labels.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to solve.. Can you guide me how to to that?